# NightwatchJS - no such file or directory for reports XML files

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, automated-tests

I keep getting the error `no such file or directory` for the report XML files after my tests are successfully run. It seems to be looking in the wrong directory:

```
no such file or directory 'E:\source\test\nightwatch\reports\E:\source\test\nightwatch\tests\file1.xml'
```

I've played around with the `settings.json`, to no avail. Any ideas how to get it to successfully create the report?

**NightwatchJS version:** 0.2.7

**Folder structure**:

```
/source
- /test
  - /nightwatch
    - nightwatch.js
    - settings.json
    - /reports
    - /screenshots
    - /tests
      - file1.js
      - file2.js
      - file3.js
- /node_modules
  - /nightwatch
    - [nightwatch files]
- app.server.js
- [other files for my app]
```

**nightwatch.js**:

```
require('nightwatch/bin/runner.js');
```

**settings.json**:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "C:/Program Files/Selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar",
    "log_path" : "reports",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444  
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "port"  : 4444,
      "silent": true,
      "firefox_profile": false,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "path" : "screenshots"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample output**:

```
E:\source\test\nightwatch>node nightwatch.js -t tests/file1.js
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  7472
Running tests

[ E:\source\test\nightwatch\tests\file1 module ]

Running:  Test File1
✔  [some assertions here...]
OK. 6 assertions passed.

fs.js:427
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'E:\source\test\nightwatch\reports\E:\source\test\nightwatch\tests\file1.xml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:966:15)
    at E:\source\node_modules\nightwatch\runner\reporters\junit.js:36:10
    at fs.js:266:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running an outdated nightwatch version which has a bug on saving report files on Windows. Latest version available is 0.3.7. 
To update to the latest version you can run:

```
npm update nightwatch
```

Comment: is it okay to just download from GitHub and copy-paste to my `node_modules/nightwatch` folder? because doing `npm update nightwatch` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating your settings for src and output to relative to runner:

```
"src_folders": ["./tests"],
"output_folder": "./reports",
```